# Why is a one-dimensional brownian motion intrinsicly stationary, but a two-dimensional isn't?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stationary-processes

In my script it says, a one-dimensional brownian motion intrinsicly stationary, but a two-dimensional isn't. I can't understand why. Can someone please help me? (Instrinsically stationary means that the increments ($\Delta ^{(h)}Y_s := Y_{s+h} - Y_{s} , s \in I $) are weakly stationary.
Thank you.